# UBOs and their alignments in Vulkan

Tags: shader, vulkan

```
struct Light {

   glm::vec4 position;
   glm::vec4 color;
   glm::vec4 attenuation;

};

struct UBO {

   // View and projection matrix
   glm::mat4 view;
   glm::mat4 proj;

   // Fog
   glm::vec4 skyColor;
   float density;
   float gradient;

   // Clipping plane
   glm::vec4 clippingPlane;

   // Lights
   Light lights[4];

};
```

Vulkan API:

The UBO struct is updated each frame and then passed to a vertex shader each over a Uniform Buffer. 
The rendered image has wrong colors because the light-array is not passed properly.

Vertex shader binding:

```
layout (binding = 1) uniform UBO {

    // View and projection matrix
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;

    // Fog
    vec4 skyColor;
    float density;
    float gradient;

    // Clipping plane
    vec4 clippingPlane;

    // Lights
    Light lights[4];

} ubo;
```

Do I need to align the data somehow?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the spec:

**Standard Uniform Buffer Layout**

The 'base alignment' of the type of an OpTypeStruct member of is defined recursively as follows:

- A scalar of size N has a base alignment of N.
- A two-component vector, with components of size N, has a base alignment of 2 N.
- A three- or four-component vector, with components of size N, has a base alignment of 4 N.
- An array has a base alignment equal to the base alignment of its element type, rounded up to a multiple of 16.
- A structure has a base alignment equal to the largest base alignment of any of its members, rounded up to a multiple of 16.
- A row-major matrix of C columns has a base alignment equal to the base alignment of a vector of C matrix components.
- A column-major matrix has a base alignment equal to the base alignment of the matrix column type.

The **std140** layout in GLSL satisfies these rules.

More about this in the [15.6.4. Offset and Stride Assignment](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#interfaces-resources-layout) section of the specification.